# Vonage transfer of call via inline ncco not working properly python

Tags: python, vonage

I am currently having an issue with Vonages Voice API. This issue specifically occurs while handling the transfer of a call via inline ncco, I am using the python code snippet from the documentation, which you can find [here.](https://developer.vonage.com/voice/voice-api/code-snippets/transfer-a-call-inline-ncco) When I paste the code from the snippet with no changes into my script, the call just plays the first action and hangs up, when trying to update that call, I am receiving the following error:

`vonage.errors.ClientError: 400 response from api.nexmo.com`

I've been searching for multiple hours but can't find anyone with a similar problem nor another person with a working implementation of this feature.

My code looks as follows:

```
import vonage

client = vonage.Client(
    application_id="<ID>",
    private_key=r"private.key",
)

voice = vonage.Voice(client)


response = voice.create_call({
    'to': [{'type': 'phone', 'number': "<mynumber>"}],
    'from': {'type': 'phone', 'number': "<vonagenumber>"},
    "ncco": [
        {
            "action": "talk",
            "text": "This is just a text whilst you tranfer to another NCCO"
        }
    ]
})

response = voice.update_call(
    response["uuid"], {
        "action": "transfer",
        "destination": {
            "type": "ncco",
            "ncco": [{"action": "talk", "text": "hello world"}]
        }
    }
)


print(response)
```

I don't know what to do with this error since it isn't defined in vonages documentation but my guess would be that it occurs because the call is already over by the time the script tries to update said call. Sadly vonage doesn't give any information on how to deal with this and the documentation only has this code snippet which is not working or at the very least incomplete.

Comment: Your assumption is likely correct about the phone call being over. You can add a stream action to your first NCCO which will play audio to keep the call alive. We will get the snippet updated too.


```
,
                        {
                            action: 'stream',
                            streamUrl: ['https://onhold2go.co.uk/song-demos/free/a-new-life-preview.mp3'],
                            loop: '0'
                        }
```

apologies about the code formatting

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried implementing this and the audio did start streaming but the code finished with the same error even before the call was complete.

Comment: did you use "loop: 0" ? this will keep it looping indefinitely. please share your updated initial NCCO

Comment: sorry for the code formatting

Comment: might want to edit out your numbers

Comment: I didn't at first but I implemented it now: The issue sadly still persists. This is my updated NCCO response = voice.create_call({ 'to': [{'type': 'phone', 'number': "<mynumber>"}], 'from': {'type': 'phone', 'number': "<vonagenumber>"}, "ncco": [ { "action": "talk", "text": "This is just a text whilst you tranfer to another NCCO" }, { "action": "stream", "streamUrl": ["onhold2go.co.uk/song-demos/free/a-new-life-preview.mp3"], "loop": 0 } ] })

Comment: do you hear the "This is just a text whilst you tranfer to another NCCO"?

Comment: No it crashes at the update call method so that never even get's called, I still receive the call and the first ncco is being played

Comment: to clarify, im asking if the first NCCO is working as expected. So if you comment out the update call method, do you get a call and hear the stream music being looped?

Comment: Yes the first NCCO is always working even if the update call is not commented out

Comment: do you get any more information from the failed update call method? or just the 400 line you posted in the original question?

Comment: I only get that error code, and the documentation seemingly doesn't cover this error code so it seems like it could also be a issue on vonages side.

Comment: can you try putting a sleep between the two method calls please?

Comment: Awesome that actually worked thanks, thanks a lot. Do you want to put it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few race condition issues, the first NCCO, and therefore call, could end before your transfer happens. If you are just testing you can add a stream action to the first NCCO to keep that call alive:

```
[
    {
        "action": "talk",
        "text": "This is just a text whilst you tranfer to another NCCO"
    },
    {
        "action": "stream",
        "streamUrl": [
            "onhold2go.co.uk/song-demos/free/a-new-life-preview.mp3"
        ],
        "loop": "0"
    }
]
```

Secondly, if you call transfer immediately after the call is made, it is possible the call has not been set up yet. You can add a sleep between the two calls to remedy this. You wouldn't really run into these issues when working with normal calls. We will update the python snippet to reflect this.